# Rails Sidekiq - Mailer class unrecognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I'm using sidekiq with rails 5 for background jobs and I wanna deliver emails in that way too. Have the following setup on my gemfile:

```
gem 'redis-rails'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra', github: 'sinatra/sinatra', require: false
gem 'devise-async'
```

I have also set the initializer:

```
Devise::Async.backend = :sidekiq
```

And call my mailer method like:

```
Mailer.delay.signup_email(@user, @password)
```

On sidekiq log, I get the error

```
2016-10-26T19:02:09.473Z 17854 TID-ww0i8 WARN: ArgumentError: undefined class/module Mailer
```

my mailer.rb file is on app/mailers folder. I restarted my rails server, redis server, sidekiq and I still get the error. Anyone knows how to fix it? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mailer is a really bad name for the class and may not autoload for that reason.  Give it a more specific name, UserMailer or such, and move it to user_mailer.rb.

Comment: Why mailer would be a bad name? Anyway, tried that and still get the error ArgumentError: undefined class/module UserMailer :/

Comment: Because there may already be a Mailer class defined at the top-level by another gem.